# Maya API Python symmetry table with MRichSelection?

Tags: python, maya

I was wondering if there is a way to access the symmetry table of the MRichSelection having as a result the positive, the seam and the negative side with the positive and the negative ordered by vertex id correspondence. ie: vertex id 15 is the symmetry correlated to vert id 350. They are both at index 5 in the positive and negative list.
I know I can achieve something similar using the filterXpand, but I believe the lists are not ordered in the way I can access the opposite vertex.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you ever found a solution to this, but I will post mine for future TD's looking for a solution.

So let's assume you want to get the corresponding verts between left and right on the YZ plane. you have 2 different options. Using the MRichSelection to handle you symmetry table. Or calculate the vert yourself, by getting the smallest distance vector on the opposite side. Note: if you use the MRichSelection method, you will need to make sure that symmetry mode is enbaled in the viewport. 
I will show both answers, so lets get started:

Also note: I will be calculating the YZ Plane, as mentioned earlier. So adjust to your liking if needed.

## Solution 1(Calculating yourself):

```
#importing the OpenMaya Module
from maya.api import OpenMaya as om
#converting selected object into MObject and MFnMesh functionset
mSel=om.MSelectionList()
mSel.add(cmds.ls(sl=1)[0])
mObj=mSel.getDagPath(0)
mfnMesh=om.MFnMesh(mObj)
#getting our basePoints
baseShape = mfnMesh.getPoints()
#this function can be used to revert the object back to the baseShape
mfnMesh.setPoints(baseShape)
#getting l and r verts
mtol=0.02# this will be our mid tolerance, if the mesh is not completely symmetric on the mid
lVerts=[]#for storing left Verts
rVerts=[]#for storing right Verts
mVerts=[]#for storing mid Verts
corrVerts={} #for storing correspondign verts
for i in range(mfnMesh.numVertices): #iteratign through all the verts on the mesh
    thisPoint = mfnMesh.getPoint(i) #getting current point position
    if thisPoint.x>0+mtol: # if pointValue on x axis is bigger than 0+midTolerance
        lVerts.append((i, thisPoint))#append to left vert storage list(i = vert index, thisPoint = vert Mpoint position)
    elif thisPoint.x<0-mtol: #opposite of left vert calculation
        rVerts.append((i, thisPoint))
    else: #if none of the above, assign to mid verts
        mVerts.append((i, thisPoint))
rVertspoints=[i for v,i in rVerts] #getting the vert mPoint positions of the right side
for vert, mp in lVerts: #going through our left points, unpacking our vert index and mPoint position()
    nmp=om.MPoint(-mp.x, mp.y, mp.z) #storing the reversed mpoint of the left side vert
    rp = mfnMesh.getClosestPoint(nmp)#getting the closest point on the mesh
    if rp[0] in rVertspoints: #cheking if the point is in the right side
        corrVerts[vert] = rVerts[rVertspoints.index(rp[0])][0] #adding it if it is true
    else:#if it is not, calculate closest vert
        #iterating through rVertspoints and find smallest distance
        dList=[nmp.distanceTo(rVert) for rVert in rVertspoints]#distance list for each vert based on input point
        mindist = min(dList)#getting the closest distance
        corrVerts[vert] = rVerts[dList.index(mindist)][0]#adding the vert
#now the corrVerts will have stored the corresponding vertices from left to right
```

## Solution 2(using MRichSelection):

```
#MAKE SURE SYMMETRY IN THE VIEWPORT IS TURNED ON TO WORK! (will also work with topological symmetry)
#importing the OpenMaya Module
from maya.api import OpenMaya as om
#converting selected object into MObject and MFnMesh functionset
mSel=om.MSelectionList()
mSel.add(cmds.ls(sl=1)[0])
mObj=mSel.getDagPath(0)
mfnMesh=om.MFnMesh(mObj)
#getting our basePoints
baseShape = mfnMesh.getPoints()
#this function can be used to revert the object back to the baseShape
mfnMesh.setPoints(baseShape)
#getting l and r verts
mtol=0.02# this will be our mid tolerance, if the mesh is not completely symmetric on the mid
lVerts=[]#for storing left Verts
corrVerts={} #for storing correspondign verts
for i in range(mfnMesh.numVertices): #iteratign through all the verts on the mesh
    thisPoint = mfnMesh.getPoint(i) #getting current point position
    if thisPoint.x>0+mtol: # if pointValue on x axis is bigger than 0+midTolerance
        lVerts.append((i, thisPoint))#append to left vert storage list(i = vert index, thisPoint = vert Mpoint position)
#selecting our verts with symmetry on
SymSelection = cmds.select(["%s.vtx[%s]"%(mObj,i)  for i,v in lVerts], sym=True)
#getting the rich selection. it will store the symmetry iformation for us
mRichBase = om.MGlobal.getRichSelection()
lCor = mRichBase.getSelection()#this will store our lSide verts as an MSelectionList
rCor = mRichBase.getSymmetry()#this will symmetry verts as an MSelectionList
mitL = om.MItSelectionList(lCor)#creating iterative lists so we can get the components
mitR = om.MItSelectionList(rCor)
while not mitL.isDone():#iterating through the left list
    mitLComp = mitL.getComponent()#getting dag path and components of leftside
    mitRComp = mitR.getComponent()#getting dag path and components of rightside
    mitLCorVert = om.MItMeshVertex(mitLComp[0], mitLComp[1]) #creating our iterative vertex lists
    mitRCorVert = om.MItMeshVertex(mitRComp[0], mitRComp[1])
    while not mitLCorVert.isDone():#iterating through our verts
        corrVerts[mitLCorVert.index()] = mitRCorVert.index()#adding corresponding verts to our dictionary
        mitLCorVert.next()#go to next vert. needed to stop loop
        mitRCorVert.next()#go to next vert. needed to stop loop
    mitL.next()#go to next selection in list if more. needed to stop loop
    mitR.next()#go to next selection in list if more. needed to stop loop
cmds.select(cl=1)#deseleting our verts
#now the corrVerts will have stored the corresponding vertices from left to right
```

Hope it will help you all, looking for a few solutions.
Cheers 
Bjarke Rauff, Rigging TD.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Bjarke Rauff was very helpful, wanted to add a note about speed.

`MFnMesh.getClosestPoint()` builds an octree to efficiently find the point, but it will do that on every call. A mesh with 100k points can take up to 45s to process.

Use a `MMeshIntersector()` to cache the data between lookups. This speeds up the table creation by 900x for 100k points to .05s.

```py
mesh # MDagpath obj to poly
flip_matrix # MTransformMatrix to flop the point
itMesh = om.MItMeshPolygon(mesh)

mesh.extendToShape()
matrix = mesh.inclusiveMatrix()
node = mesh.node()
intersector = om.MMeshIntersector()
intersector.create(node, matrix)
if not (intersector.isCreated):
    print("Failed to create mesh intersector")
    return
flipped_ids={}
while not itMesh.isDone():
    id = itMesh.index()
    face_center = itMesh.center()
    # flop the point across the axis
    flipped_point = face_center*flip_matrix
    MpointOnMesh = intersector.getClosestPoint(flipped_point)
    if MpointOnMesh is not None:
        # get face id property from MPointOnMesh
        flipped_id = MpointOnMesh.face
        flipped_ids[id] = flipped_id
    else:
        print("No intersection")
    itMesh.next()
```

NOTE
I tried hash tables with a tuple of the point as the key, but the point positions had slight variations, even with rounding,  which created different hashes.
I've tested the `MRichSelection` approach and it doesn't actually work consistently in practice. It seems like it works when you have a perfectly mirrored mesh, but that can't be assumed. The component lists are not necessarily in sync.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions 
from what I understand from reading the code, the script relies on the vertex position. 
I should have been more specific with what I want to do.
I am trying to get the topological symmetry without having to iterate through all the vertices/edges. The topological symmetry has already the mapping of the left and the right side of the vertices. I was wondering if this information can be obtained through the rich selection.